# Replace Strings In One File With Strings From Other File

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I have two directories of files, new-config-files and old-config-files:

```
new-config-files/this-db/config.inc.php
new-config-files/that-db/config.inc.php
new-config-files/old-db/config.inc.php
new-config-files/new-db/config.inc.php
new-config-files/random-database/config.inc.php
etc.

old-config-files/this-db/config.inc.php
old-config-files/that-db/config.inc.php
old-config-files/old-db/config.inc.php
old-config-files/new-db/config.inc.php
old-config-files/random-database/config.inc.php
etc.
```

Example snippet of old file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'test-user';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test-user-password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'test-data';
```

Example snippet of new file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'DB-USER';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'DB-PASSWORD';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'DB-DATABASES';
```

I'd like to replace only the stub values (i.e., DB-USER, DB-PASSWORD, DB-DATABASES) in the new config files with the corresponding actual values (i.e., test-user, test-user-password, test-data) from the old config files.

I expect values in the old files will all be alphanumeric.

It would also be good to know how to do this when there are no stub values, but only different values, that should also be replaced with the old-config values.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` and `patch` could be perfect for this:

```
diff oldfile newfile > patchfile
```

`more patchfile`

```
1,3c1,3
< $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'test-user';
< $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test-user-password';
< $cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'test-data';
---
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'DB-USER';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'DB-PASSWORD';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'DB-DATABASES';
```

`patch newfile -i patchfile -o updatedfile`

`more updatedfile`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'test-user';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test-user-password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = 'test-data';
```

More examples here: https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/introduction-using-diff-and-patch/